# Query nested json object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My document:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d880d679d3969d0592abc3"), 
  "uuid" : "1322c975-068d-4707-b5a5-f6715a9275aa", 
  "user" : "0ba127e4-e40c-4f69-a7dc-f72a93aff7f7", 
  "like" : "sdfg", 
  "dislike" : "dsfg",
  "article" : { "uuid" : "407b67e2-cda3-4cf5-b26a-ab0d5d8e4be9", "version" : 1 },
  "__v" : 0
}
```

I need to query the article by its uuid. I have tried both aggregate and find.

db.col.find({article: {uuid: "407b67e2-cda3-4cf5-b26a-ab0d5d8e4be9"}})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query it using the dot notation, check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) for further details:

```
db.data.find({"article.uuid":"407b67e2-cda3-4cf5-b26a-ab0d5d8e4be9"})
```